# Database connection issue between C# and MySQL using Mono in Unity

Tags: c#, mysql, mono, unity-game-engine

For a personal project I am trying to use MySQL to access a database I have created which stores images.  I am coding my scripts in C# but my connection refuses to open.  Here is a snippet of my code (the relevant portion):

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

string cs ="Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=password;";

MySqlConnection conn = null;
MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

try 
{
   conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
   conn.Open();

   string stm = "SELECT * FROM images";
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);
   rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (rdr.Read())
   {
      //do stuff
   }

   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      print (ex.ToString());
   } 

   finally 
   {
      if (rdr != null) 
      {
         rdr.Close();
      }

      if (conn != null) 
      {
         conn.Close();
      }
   }
```

I have put in breakpoints and the culprit is the conn.Open() function.  At that point it throws an exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTrace ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler.Create'. at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_Settings () [0x00000] in :0   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource..ctor (System.String name, SourceLevels sourceLevels) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource..ctor (System.String name) [0x00000] in :0    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTrace..cctor () [0x00000] in :0
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) [0x00000] in :0  UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object) UIScript:Start() (at Assets/UIScript.cs:123)

It sounds to me like an old/mismatched dll but I brought in MySql.Data, I18N, and I18N.West as a couple of solutions suggested while I was googling.  I have run out of suggested fixes and I hope someone can help.  I am using MySQL 5.6 and .Net Connector 5.6.6.